# Revelatory versus revealing

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I looked up these two words in many dictionaries; the only difference I could find was that *revealing* can be used to describe clothing that overly discloses human body, like a revealing blouse, **but in terms of information, secrets or insights..., how could they be differentiated?**

Comment: You usually use revealing with news, information  insight, moment, etc .  Revelatory is more common with experience.  Revelatory is more formal.

Answer (score 4):

With **revelatory**, the knowledge of that which is revealed is usually beneficial to or of concern to those to whom it was revealed; they have had their eyes opened; they have been enlightened by the revelation:

> It was a revelatory experience.
>
> The revelatory memo documented how the company had been dumping toxic waste into the river for decades.

To call the memo **revealing** would be to say that it had divulged secrets. To call it **revelatory** would be to focus on the *value* of those secrets to those to whom the information had been revealed.

> When the presidential candidate referred to citizens at the lower end of the economic spectrum as "takers", it was a revealing moment. The electorate certainly found those words revelatory.